# MySQL add some hours when set default column datetime

Tags: mysql, timestamp, alter-table

I want to add some hours when alter table datetime to default current_timestamp

here the sql queries were I tried :

```
 ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY COLUMN created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR);

 ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY COLUMN created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 7 HOUR;

 ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY COLUMN created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() + INTERVAL 7 HOUR;
```

but none of them work, please share me if you know how to solved this case.

Comment: Why not  create a trigger on before insert

Comment: great idea, actually if it possible, I want to know how it can be done via alter query.

Comment: I didn't know this, but you can't add hours to a default value in MySQL.  You'll have to use a trigger, q.v. the duplicate link.

Comment: hmm..,so it not possible to add hours to a default value in MySQL...it means my case can be applied only by trigger..okay thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Trigger Try below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER [trigger_name]
BEFORE INSERT
ON [table_name] FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SET NEW.created_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 7 HOUR;

END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

And then try to insert data into your table.

Comment: Hi @Rehan, thanks for your trigger query :)

Comment: Did it work? if yes please accept the answer.

Comment: okay but maybe it's need some editing, since it not possible to add hours via default value.., your answer is right for my case. thank you